# ManyToMany in javax.persistence allow duplicate entries

Tags: java, mysql, persistence, entitymanager

I have a table called *Order* which has many *Items*, so I need a map to link the *Items* to the *Order*.

At the moment I have this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinTable(name = "order_map_item", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "itemId"))
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

but it doesn't allow duplicates if I want to add an Item twice.

When I edit the MySql database by hand and remove the index, I can add duplicates. But they are getting more if I call `em.refresh(order);`

Please tell me, what is best practice for my case? Can't find anything...

Comment: sounds like a One to Many case. One order has many items.

Comment: no there are Items like, 'Beer', 'Cola' & 'Water'. I want to map them to the order... so order 1 has ['Beer','Beer','Water'] And one Item can be at multiple orders, multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is that the join table has obviously a composite primary  key with each column as foregn key to both the tables.
However your use case dictates that there may be repetition. In this case, an alternate strategy could be a mapping entity

```
@Entity
public class OrderItemMapping  {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long                id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order")
    private Order               order;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="item")
    private Item item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Order Class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Item> items;
```

Items Class:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL} )
@JoinColumn(name = "orderId")
private Order order;
```